# Combine several variables of different data types into one string

Tags: django, string-concatenation

I'd like to combine 6 variables that are of different types in my view...I thought the concatenation '+' will work but I get an error when I use it.  I'd like the end result to be like this:

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 (var5 var6)
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem you had with using `+` is that not all of the variables are strings. Use the following but replace `%s` with an applicable formatter from [this list](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

```
output_string = "%s %s %s %s (%s %s)" % (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

Another option is to pass them to your template and output them there:

```
{{ var1 }} {{ var2 }} {{ var3 }} {{ var4 }} ({{ var5 }} {{ var6 }})
```

Comment: I'd just gotten the same solution to work...seems I freaked out before I thought out everything straight.  Thnx lemonad